# What ACL commands are required for Master-Replica synchronization in Redis 6?

Tags: redis, acl

When configuring Redis 6 with ACLs in a cluster environment an additional user must be created (assuming the default user is not desired or does not have access to the PSYNC command). What are the exact commands that must be assigned to this user?

There is a small note about **ACL rules for Sentinel and Replicas** [in the documentation](https://redis.io/topics/acl) indicating that Sentinel needs:

> AUTH, CLIENT, SUBSCRIBE, SCRIPT, PUBLISH, PING, INFO, MULTI, SLAVEOF,
> CONFIG, CLIENT, EXEC

and replicas need:

> PSYNC, REPLCONF, PING

My best guess is to combine the two for a command set of:

> AUTH, CLIENT, SUBSCRIBE, SCRIPT, PUBLISH, PING, INFO, MULTI, SLAVEOF,
> CONFIG, CLIENT, EXEC, PSYNC, REPLCONF

Excerpt from redis.conf which indicates *"and/or other commands needed for replication"*:

```
# If the master is password protected (using the "requirepass" configuration
# directive below) it is possible to tell the replica to authenticate before
# starting the replication synchronization process, otherwise the master will
# refuse the replica request.
#
masterauth mymasterpassword
#
# However this is not enough if you are using Redis ACLs (for Redis version
# 6 or greater), and the default user is not capable of running the PSYNC
# command and/or other commands needed for replication. In this case it's
# better to configure a special user to use with replication, and specify the
# masteruser configuration as such:
#
masteruser mymasteruser
#
# When masteruser is specified, the replica will authenticate against its
# master using the new AUTH form: AUTH <username> <password>.
```

Comment: I am currently testing AUTH, PING, INFO, MULTI, SLAVEOF, EXEC, PSYNC, and REPLCONF with success. I believe I can pull a few more commands off of that list.

Comment: Do you happen to find out the list of commands needed for replica?